# Maven dependancy specification in pom file

Tags: java, maven

Let's say I have three projects

Project A

Project B

Project C

Now project B has a dependency on C, and so does Project A, but Project A also has a dependency on Project B.

B->C

A->B

A->C

In maven pom files, how should it be specified?

Does it suffice to include the dependency on B, and as B is dependant on C, C doesn't have to be explicitly mentioned in A's pom file?

Comment: Dependencies are declared within <dependecies> tag of pom.xml file. And you dont need to expilicitly mention C in A's pom file because it's transitive dependency. Unless you want to specify a different version of C other than which version the B is depending on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, maven dependencies are transitive. Check - http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html